# spacy: can i make token in to string?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I am now making a program to change sentence structure into Korean sentence structure via spacy
ex) I love you -> I you love
the problem is that I don't know how to change doc to string
is there any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! How about this:

```
doc.text
```

Let me know if that works!